# How to remove or hide the front right arrow of kotlin file in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I use android stuio in win10, and every kotlin file I create, with a right arrow in front, I can see all the methods in this kotlin file, but I do not want them, I just want see a kt file, then if I want to see detail, I just double click it, I hate the right arrow, anyone knows how to remove or hide it?

Comment: You might want to take a screenshot, annotate it to point out what "right arrow" you are referring to, upload that screenshot somewhere, and link to it from your question.

Comment: If I understand what you're talking about, configure the tree to **not** "Show Members" (that's what the setting is called in IntelliJ; not sure about Android Studio).

Comment: @Slaw in android studio it is called the same